# [Vue warn]:Unknown custom element: ... -did you register the component correctly?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, components, telerik, telerik-grid

When you get

> [Vue warn]: Unknown custom element: `<...>` - did you register the component correctly?
> For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option.
> found in ---> `<...>` src/views/....vue `<App>` at src/....vue `<Root>`

[image: vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:619 [Vue warn]: Unknown custom element: - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option. found in ---> at src/views/Dashboard.vue at src/App.vue]

you might have forgotten to install dependencies

Answer (score -1):

I know this is silly mistake but it can save your time.
Sometime you have lots of work and you copy and paste form online solution, then you add dependencies in your code but forgot to install all the dependencies which you include in your **vue-js** project/code.

Please check you have installed all dependencies or not.